# Div elements are not rendering on site but displayed in inspector

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a website I am developing:

https://dynamictech.ca/dummy_page_debug/

I am not sure what is going on but some div's are not showing up on my site. The code is there in the inspector -- but not on the page.

In the link above you can see between "stuff should be here:" and "and end here." there is a bunch of stuff that should be displayed (again, it's in the inspector but not on the page).

I am running a wordpress plugin as well that works with woocommerce. If I remove the shortcode that displays the plugin stuff the above does get displayed correctly -- so something somewhere the plugin is interfering with displaying the divs? it's very strange.

See it working here: https://dynamictech.ca/dummy_page_debug2/

PHP issue? I have tried to up max_input_vars from 1000 to 3000 to 5000 to even 20000 -- nothing works.

Please help.

Comment: When in doubt, go up and up and up in the inspector. `.fusion-faqs-wrapper` has `display:none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a style:

```
.fusion-faqs-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

That is causing those element to be hidden on the first page.
The same style exists on the second page, but an inline style of `display: block` is being applied. There appears to be something up with your javascript that is not allowing those elements to be revealed.

> TypeError: field_value_1 is undefined

I think you're issue is client-side, not server-side.

Comment: Where do you see that TypeError? 

Is this something the plugins author should fix as it's over my head...

Comment: @sci-guy I was seeing it appear in the Console of the browser developer tools (Press F12, works for most browsers on Windows)